# Prestashop 1.7 - invoices should be in other languages when backoffice language is English

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am still newbie in PrestaShop. Our customer wants English language in back-office menu, but invoices must be generated in other languages: Lithuanian, Latvian, Estonian (depending where customer came from). The problem is that English language is set in back-office, but invoices from orders are also generated in English (they should be generated in Lithuanian). I was thinking that it could be simple solution, to override/extend HTMLTemplateInvoiceCore class as HTMLTemplateInvoice class, and to set property "language" of Context object by id of language from order in class constructor:

```
<?php

class HTMLTemplateInvoice extends HTMLTemplateInvoiceCore
{
    public $order;
    public $order_invoice;
    public $available_in_your_account = false;

    /**
     * @param OrderInvoice $order_invoice
     * @param $smarty
     *
     * @throws PrestaShopException
     */
    public function __construct(OrderInvoice $order_invoice, $smarty, $bulk_mode = false)
    {
        $this->order_invoice = $order_invoice;
        $this->order = new Order((int) $this->order_invoice->id_order);
        $this->smarty = $smarty;

        // If shop_address is null, then update it with current one.
        // But no DB save required here to avoid massive updates for bulk PDF generation case.
        // (DB: bug fixed in 1.6.1.1 with upgrade SQL script to avoid null shop_address in old orderInvoices)
        if (!isset($this->order_invoice->shop_address) || !$this->order_invoice->shop_address) {
            $this->order_invoice->shop_address = OrderInvoice::getCurrentFormattedShopAddress((int) $this->order->id_shop);
            if (!$bulk_mode) {
                OrderInvoice::fixAllShopAddresses();
            }
        }

        // header informations
        $this->date = Tools::displayDate($order_invoice->date_add);

        // switch language to order language - language property is really set up correctly:
        Context::getContext()->language = new Language($this->order->id_lang);

        //id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
        $id_lang = $this->order->id_lang;
        $this->title = $order_invoice->getInvoiceNumberFormatted($id_lang);

        $this->shop = new Shop((int) $this->order->id_shop);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it still does not work properly: property $id_lang of order is "2" (Lithuanian language), but invoice is still being output in English language. Context property $language is being correctly set (I have inspected it). What am I doing wrong and what should be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I needed to set translator in Context object, by locale. Here is my full extended/overrriden HTMLTemplateInvoice class:

```
<?php

class HTMLTemplateInvoice extends HTMLTemplateInvoiceCore
{
    public $order;
    public $order_invoice;
    public $available_in_your_account = false;

    /**
     * @param OrderInvoice $order_invoice
     * @param $smarty
     *
     * @throws PrestaShopException
     */
    public function __construct(OrderInvoice $order_invoice, $smarty, $bulk_mode = false)
    {
        $this->order_invoice = $order_invoice;
        $this->order = new Order((int) $this->order_invoice->id_order);
        $this->smarty = $smarty;

        // If shop_address is null, then update it with current one.
        // But no DB save required here to avoid massive updates for bulk PDF generation case.
        // (DB: bug fixed in 1.6.1.1 with upgrade SQL script to avoid null shop_address in old orderInvoices)
        if (!isset($this->order_invoice->shop_address) || !$this->order_invoice->shop_address) {
            $this->order_invoice->shop_address = OrderInvoice::getCurrentFormattedShopAddress((int) $this->order->id_shop);
            if (!$bulk_mode) {
                OrderInvoice::fixAllShopAddresses();
            }
        }

        // header informations
        $this->date = Tools::displayDate($order_invoice->date_add);

        if (Context::getContext()->employee != null) {
            Context::getContext()->language = new Language($this->order->id_lang);
            Context::getContext()->shop = new Shop($this->order->id_shop);
            Context::getContext()->setTranslatorFromLocale(Context::getContext()->language->locale);
        }


        $id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
        $this->title = $order_invoice->getInvoiceNumberFormatted($id_lang);

        $this->shop = new Shop((int) $this->order->id_shop);
    }

    
}
```

And here is my extended/overriden Context class:

```
class Context extends ContextCore
{
    public function setTranslatorFromLocale($locale)
    {
        $translator = $this->getTranslatorFromLocale($locale);
        // In case we have at least 1 translated message, we return the current translator.
        if (count($translator->getCatalogue($locale)->all())) {
            $this->translator = $translator;
        }

        $this->translator = $translator;
    }
}
```